# Ordend e ejecucion de AjaxRequest incorrecto

Tags: ajax, extjs

estoy desarrollando en EXTJS y al momento de usar un Ajax Request, siempre ocurre un orden de ejecucion de codigo que me entorpece las validaciones.

Este es el problema:

Un ejemplo, Llamo los parametros al archivo guardar_avance.php.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'json/guardar_avance.php?accion=remuneracion',
    scope: this,
    params: {
        tipo_ingreso: form_nuevoContrato.getForm().findField('cmb_tipoUsuario').getValue(),
        mper_rut: form_nuevoContrato.getForm().findField('rut').getValue(),
        mper_dv: form_nuevoContrato.getForm().findField('dv').getValue(),
    },
    success: function (resp, request)
    {   var guardarRemuneracionOk = true;
        var respuestaremuneracion = Ext.util.JSON.decode(resp.responseText);

    }

if (guardarRemuneracionOk == true){
```

}

El problema es que se ejecuta el Ajax Request, y al momento de llegar al success no entra en el, sino que salta al codigo de abajo , o sea al IF, y luego vuelve al inicio del Ajax Request, y al final de todo vuelve al success y si ingresa a él

Esto me produce problemas cuando necesito ejecutar codigo despues del ajax, (por ejemplo el IF), que me comprueba q sucedio con la variable guardarRemuneracionOk , pero al saltarse el success en la primera ejecucion, este IF se invalida y no me sirve, ya que no sabe que sucedio con esa variable al no ejecutarse de primeras el success.

Como puedo arreglar ese orden de ejecucion para q a la primera corrida ingrese al succes y asi el IF pueda verificar correctamente?.

muchas gracias!!

Comment: No conozco `extjs`, pero por lo que conozco de peticiones Ajax vía jQuery, el `if` me parece que debería ir dentro del `success`, no fuera de él, ya que si no hay éxito (success) en la petición no podrás evaluar la variable. Imagino que debería existir un método que maneje los posibles fracasos (fail) de la petición.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se presenta porque la llamada Ajax esta asincronica.

agrega la propiedad async con valor en false **async:false**

```
Ext.Ajax.request({  
    async:false,  
    url: 'json/guardar_avance.php?accion=remuneracion',  
    scope: this,  
    params: {  
        tipo_ingreso:   form_nuevoContrato.getForm().findField('cmb_tipoUsuario').getValue(),  
        mper_rut: form_nuevoContrato.getForm().findField('rut').getValue(),  
        mper_dv: form_nuevoContrato.getForm().findField('dv').getValue(),  
    },  
    success: function (resp, request){  
        var guardarRemuneracionOk = true;  
        var respuestaremuneracion = Ext.util.JSON.decode(resp.responseText);  
    }
);  
if (guardarRemuneracionOk == true){}
```

Answer (score -1):

Gracias A Cedano, lo que pasa es que hay varios Ajax correlativos, y cada uno debiera arrojarme un true si entra al success, y una vez que pasen todos los ajax request, ahi verifico si todos me arrojaron true o alguno se mantuvo en false, por eso no podria colocar el if dentro del success, por q son varios.

Comment: Esto es un comentario no una respuesta, por favor colócala donde debe de ir.